# IntelliJ - Java files appear with extentions

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, bitbucket, git-commit

I have a problem with IntelliJ. I'm working on the Maven project and I use Bitbucket Git repository. Java files appear with their extensions. Also, when I make a change and try to commit, changes do not appear on the commit page.  I do not understand if it is about git repo or another thing. How can I solve that problem?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNPlC.png)

Thanks.

Comment: go to  file-->project structure and make sure that you have set project SDK correctly

Comment: I checked that Java jdk1.8.0_161 is already setted

Comment: and what about ```project language level``` in same window

Comment: language level is 8

Comment: right-click on project name on project side panel and click ```Add framework support``` then check ```Maven``` then click ```Ok```

Comment: I've added Maven framework but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our folder with source code is not tagged as a source code folder in the project setting. So IntelliJ use the files not as part of the project.

src for example should be tagged as source code.

Comment: This solution helps, thanks!